# umount: target is busy

Tags: linux, mount

I have mounted `/dev` and immediately tried to unmount:

```
$ sudo mount -o rbind /dev m
$ sudo umount m
umount: /tmp/m: target is busy.
$ sudo lsof m
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
kdevtmpfs  55 root  cwd    DIR    0,6     4420    2 m
kdevtmpfs  55 root  rtd    DIR    0,6     4420    2 m
```

I have read that `fuser` can kill processes accessing the mount point, but I would like to understand what is happening in this simple case. Acording to the `lsof` output does something use the mountpoint as current working directory (cwd)?

I do not want to use lazy unmount.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You used `rbind` to mount a filesystem and submounts.  In order to unmount a filesystem, you must unmount its submounts first (and the same for their submounts, recursively).  But take care!

```
mount --make-rslave m
umount -R m
```

Without the first command, you risk unmounting all the sub-mounts on the *source*, due to mount propagation.  In this case that means all the sub-mounts of `/dev`, which would have bad effects on your running system ;-).

Basically mount propagation is a massive pit-trap waiting for you to fall into it :-).  It seems like it would have been better if bind mounts disabled it by default.

---

`kdevtmpfs` is the kernel thread that maintains devtmpfs.  It does not prevent unmounting devtmpfs.  This is because the kernel thread runs on a separate mount (like a bind mount).  You can't see that original mount; it is in a separate mount namespace.  If you want to try and work out why `kdevtmpfs` shows up in `lsof`, I don't know, maybe consider that a separate question.