# umount /chrootedpath /dev/pts after several chroot(s): target is busy

Tags: devices, chroot, pts

I've been doing several chrooted environments in parallel, each in separate folder (when the script with `chroot` exited I sometimes run another in same folder), and for a while it seemed fine. But now I have almost empty `/dev` of "main" system (cannot start apps/open new windows, etc.).

I've been mounting like this:

```
sudo mount -t proc proc $work_path/fin_sq/proc
sudo mount -t sysfs sys $work_path/fin_sq/sys
sudo mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs $work_path/fin_sq/dev
sudo mount -t devpts devpts $work_path/fin_sq/dev/pts
```

and unmounting after exiting `chroot`:

```
umount "${work_path}"/fin_sq/dev/pts
umount "${work_path}"/fin_sq/dev
umount "${work_path}"/fin_sq/proc
umount "${work_path}"/fin_sq/sys
```

Occasionally I've interrupted script running in chrooted environment via `ctrl-c`. For cases when the script run in a folder where there were remnants of previous run, the script is coded to umount and delete previous work.

Today I saw `target is busy` at least in one terminal window where I run script with `chroot`. After `umount` failed the script deleted all folders of chrooted system. For the future, I think I better cancel further unmounts/deletions if one of umounts fails.

However, what do you think might cause such result? How to investigate? How to get system to working condition? I'm not rebooting the system for a while hoping to learn Linux deeper. TIA

P.S. full script(s) for those interested: [script running other script via chroot](https://github.com/mars4science/Bash-scripts-to-enhance-amend-Linux-distro-before-and-after-installation/blob/main/_make_custom_liveusb.sh), searching for `/dev/pts` finds two lines (mount/umount) in the code.

"Naturally" `lsof` shows empty output and adding `--force` seems to make no difference. Trying `mount -t devpts devpts /dev` resulted in "devtmpfs already mounted on one_of_chrooted_paths/dev".

I've read [umount: target is busy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464585/umount-target-is-busy), but the question is for `-o rbind`, I mount w/out it. Again, it was working with two chrooted, I increased to 3-4 and something broke...

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** this answer is how I solved the issue, answers on technical details how it possibly had happened are welcome.

I've found with `ps aux` couple of `sudo chroot .../work5/` processes with `T` and `Ss` status respectively.

***TL:DR***

Also several other processes which I've found once I run `lsof` for another subfolder in `chroot` I saw still mounted in `findmnt` (not "${work_path}"/fin_sq/dev/pts which I checked earlier). After those were terminated (not easily, I've posted another related question: [linux: kill -9 process success only on second attempt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/759479/linux-kill-9-process-success-only-on-second-attempt)), I was able to unmount problematic mount points.

After that I had damaged `/dev`, in particular `/dev/null` was not `special character`, I fixed that finding googling my own answer in https://superuser.com/a/1767579/607929:

```
# mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3 
# mknod -m 666 /dev/ptmx c 5 2
```

All seems to work, particulars of how exactly issue started will be INO even harder to find. Looks like I've cleared terminal output of previous run of script for `chroot` before running next. `Ctrl-c` was almost certainly the root cause. I wonder why it interrupted before many times w/out issues but recently resulted in such "mess".